# Allow specific ips in scpecific port

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I'm trying to allow my ip address to connect remotely to a specific port, so in my remote machine i put this :

```
 iptables -P INPUT DROP
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4848 -s myip@ -j ACCEPT
```

So when i try to connect with :

```
 ip@remotemachine:4848
```

nothings happen but if i disable the firewall or switch the policy to `ACCEPT`

```
 iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT 

 service iptables stop
```

I can access to my remote machine, any ideas how to solve this ?

Comment: Why do you have a @ on the end of 'myIP' in the source? I'm presuming it's something like web serving or ssh you're using?

Comment: yes its a web server.

Answer (score -1):

The problem i was using proxy. i didn't notice that so when i ran `tcpdump` in my server i found another address (proxy address) not my address this is why my rules didn't worke.